# Fill empty pandas dataframe with data from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to fill an empty dataframe using a list.

Here is the empty dataframe.

```
old_dates= pd.date_range((today -dt.timedelta(days=2)), (today-dt.timedelta(days=1))).strftime("%d %b")
columns=old_dates
df_verif=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
df_verif


24 Jun  25 Jun
```

All of the column names are dates (and will be longer through time). I then want to fill only the first row with one value for each day. Let's say I have a list that contains two values. How would I then add those values, in the order that they appear in the list, under the corresponding date?

```
test=[2.5,2.5]
```

Expected output:

```
0   24 Jun  25 Jun
1   2.5     2.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, it should be:

`df_verif.loc[0] = test`

This adds the elements of test to the row at index 0 in the order in which they are in test.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add `test = [2.5, 2.5]` at the end of DataFrame (without explicitly set the row number):

```
df_verif = df_verif.append({k:v for k,v in zip(columns,test)},  ignore_index=True )

df_verif

Out[1]:

    24 Jun  25 Jun
0   2.5     2.5
```